# In Golang how can you convert [32]byte to uint64 and then reverse back to [32]byte

Tags: arrays, go

I thought I had a good option with the binary package.

but My32ByteArray does not equal Restored32ByteArray

```
My32ByteArray := []byte{202, 79, 31, 160, 8, 87, 74, 158, 67, 245, 189, 58, 2, 168, 77, 65, 5, 53, 99, 81, 216, 156, 41, 36, 248, 179, 206, 111, 178, 71, 225, 77}
Restored32ByteArray :=[]byte{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
TheUint64 = binary.BigEdian.Uint64(My32ByteArray) 

binary.BigEdian.PutUint64(Restored32ByteArray, TheUint64)
```

It does work for the first 8 bytes but the rest of the byte array is left at zeros
I get the following 32byte array

```
202 79 31 160 8 87 74 158 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Is there a way to use binary package for this or is it limited to 8 byte arrays or is there another way that will work for this?
```

Comment: This is because you are storing 32 *bytes* into *8* bytes (or 64 *bits*) - uint64 is 64 *bits*, which is 64/8 = 8 bytes. Hence when decoding into a zeroed byte slice, it sets only the first 8 bytes of it.

Comment: Yeah figured it out and was going to update thanks for the quick response just been a long day.  Thanks,